# Is it possible to get the current state of the application history?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

After navigating through the application to build up some history, is it possible to get the list of previous routes you visited?

Attempting to debug an issue where the back but just loops between the last 2 routes.

Comment: Maybe a dumb answer, but how about long press the back button in Chrome?

Comment: Not dumb at all, I tried that and see the history  but,  the application history isn't matching.